# Update a Google Doc (or file stored with Docs) with PHP

Tags: php, google-api, google-docs

It seems Zend Gdata doesn't provide a way to interface with the [PUT API for Google Docs](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#UpdatingContent).
I'd like to clear a document with a known id and update its contents.

Should I authenticate with Zend's Gdata and use an HTTP PUT request? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two choices:

1. Pray Zend developers to add this feature in some future release
2. Download Zend sources and try to tweak them to add this feature

I have downloaded Zend sources and what i see is:

1. demos\Docs.php already talks with Google docs (retrieve docs), you could try it from command line
2. Gdata\App.php has already put function!

I would create a new method `updateDocument` in Gdata\Docs.php that calls App.php using put and passing the parameters required [here](http://code.google.com/intl/it/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#UpdatingContent); once created i would add this call to demos\Docs.php starting to play with it.

Comment: +1 Adding extra functionality to Gdata_Docs is the way to go, the API should be robust enough to allow adding extra functionality like this.